# Regex with exceptions to certain keywords

Tags: regex, string, stylish

I am trying to create regex expression (to use with Stylish extension for Firefox) that will render **true** for every string that has `youtube.com`, however will render **false** if string contains `/user/` or `/channel/`.

Example

```
True
https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending

False
https://www.youtube.com/user/whateva/featured
https://www.youtube.com/channel/lfjafjsldsf
```

I don't even know where to start, tried to learn regex several times, but its beyond my understanding how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
^.*youtube\.com((?!\/user\/|\/channel\/).)*$
```

See **[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/3VCW4p/1/)**

Proposed solution is using negative lookahead. For more information on that see:

- [Regex tutorial on lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)